# jupyter notebook error when fetching olivetti_faces

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyerror

I wanted to use olivetti_faces dataset at jupyter notebook. When I ran the following code, dataset was not downloaded with the following error:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
faces = fetch_olivetti_faces()
```

error:

> TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last) File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1354, in
> AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
>
> 1353 try:
> -> 1354     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,    1355
> encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1356 except
> OSError as err: # timeout error
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1255, in
> HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers,
> encode_chunked)    1254 """Send a complete request to the server."""
> -> 1255 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1301, in
> HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers,
> encode_chunked)    1300     body = _encode(body, 'body')
> -> 1301 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1250, in
> HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)    1249
> raise CannotSendHeader()
> -> 1250 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1010, in
> HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
> 1009 del self._buffer[:]
> -> 1010 self.send(msg)    1012 if message_body is not None:    1013     1014     # create a consistent interface to message_body
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:950, in
> HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
> 949 if self.auto_open:
> --> 950     self.connect()
> 951 else:
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1424, in
> HTTPSConnection.connect(self)    1422     server_hostname = self.host
> -> 1424 self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,    1425                                       server_hostname=server_hostname)
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py:500, in
> SSLContext.wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side,
> do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname,
> session)
> 494 def wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side=False,
> 495                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
> 496                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
> 497                 server_hostname=None, session=None):
> 498     # SSLSocket class handles server_hostname encoding before it calls
> 499     # ctx._wrap_socket()
> --> 500     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
> 501         sock=sock,
> 502         server_side=server_side,
> 503         do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
> 504         suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
> 505         server_hostname=server_hostname,
> 506         context=self,
> 507         session=session
> 508     )
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py:1040, in
> SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect,
> suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)    1039
> raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for
> non-blocking sockets")
> -> 1040         self.do_handshake()    1041 except (OSError, ValueError):
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py:1309, in
> SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)    1308
> self.settimeout(None)
> -> 1309     self._sslobj.do_handshake()    1310 finally:
>
> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [5], in <cell line: 2>()
> 1 # %load solutions/03A_faces_plot.py
> ----> 2 faces = fetch_olivetti_faces()
>
> File
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets_olivetti_faces.py:115,
> in fetch_olivetti_faces(data_home, shuffle, random_state,
> download_if_missing, return_X_y)
> 112     raise IOError("Data not found and `download_if_missing` is False")
> 114 print("downloading Olivetti faces from %s to %s" % (FACES.url, data_home))
> --> 115 mat_path = _fetch_remote(FACES, dirname=data_home)
> 116 mfile = loadmat(file_name=mat_path)
> 117 # delete raw .mat data
>
> File
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets_base.py:1454,
> in _fetch_remote(remote, dirname)    1432 """Helper function to
> download a remote dataset into path    1433     1434 Fetch a dataset
> pointed by remote's url, save into path using remote's    (...)
> 1450     Full path of the created file.    1451 """    1453 file_path
> = remote.filename if dirname is None else join(dirname, remote.filename)
> -> 1454 urlretrieve(remote.url, file_path)    1455 checksum = _sha256(file_path)    1456 if remote.checksum != checksum:
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:247, in
> urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
> 230 """
> 231 Retrieve a URL into a temporary location on disk.
> 232     (...)
> 243 data file as well as the resulting HTTPMessage object.
> 244 """
> 245 url_type, path = _splittype(url)
> --> 247 with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
> 248     headers = fp.info()
> 250     # Just return the local path and the "headers" for file://
> 251     # URLs. No sense in performing a copy unless requested.
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:222, in
> urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
> 220 else:
> 221     opener = _opener
> --> 222 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:525, in
> OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
> 522     req = meth(req)
> 524 sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
> --> 525 response = self._open(req, data)
> 527 # post-process response
> 528 meth_name = protocol+"_response"
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:542, in
> OpenerDirector._open(self, req, data)
> 539     return result
> 541 protocol = req.type
> --> 542 result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
> 543                           '_open', req)
> 544 if result:
> 545     return result
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:502, in
> OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
> 500 for handler in handlers:
> 501     func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
> --> 502     result = func(*args)
> 503     if result is not None:
> 504         return result
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1397, in
> HTTPSHandler.https_open(self, req)    1396 def https_open(self, req):
> -> 1397     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,    1398         context=self._context,
> check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1357, in
> AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
> 1354         h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data,
> headers,    1355
> encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1356     except
> OSError as err: # timeout error
> -> 1357         raise URLError(err)    1358     r = h.getresponse()
> 135
>
> 9 except:
>
> URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed
> because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed because connected host has
> failed to respond>

But when I ran that code in PyCharm, olivetti_py3.pkz was downloaded and placed in scikit_learn_data folder.
I ran the code again at the jupyter notebook, but this time I received the following error:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [6], in <cell line: 2>()
> 1 # %load solutions/03A_faces_plot.py
> ----> 2 faces = fetch_olivetti_faces()
>
> File
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets_olivetti_faces.py:124,
> in fetch_olivetti_faces(data_home, shuffle, random_state,
> download_if_missing, return_X_y)
> 122     del mfile
> 123 else:
> --> 124     faces = joblib.load(filepath)
> 126 # We want floating point data, but float32 is enough (there is only
> 127 # one byte of precision in the original uint8s anyway)
> 128 faces = np.float32(faces)
>
> File
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py:587,
> in load(filename, mmap_mode)
> 581             if isinstance(fobj, str):
> 582                 # if the returned file object is a string, this means we
> 583                 # try to load a pickle file generated with an version of
> 584                 # Joblib so we load it with joblib compatibility function.
> 585                 return load_compatibility(fobj)
> --> 587             obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
> 588 return obj
>
> File
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py:506,
> in _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
> 504 obj = None
> 505 try:
> --> 506     obj = unpickler.load()
> 507     if unpickler.compat_mode:
> 508         warnings.warn("The file '%s' has been generated with a "
> 509                       "joblib version less than 0.10. "
> 510                       "Please regenerate this pickle file."
> 511                       % filename,
> 512                       DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=3)
>
> File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py:1212, in
> _Unpickler.load(self)    1210             raise EOFError    1211         assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
> -> 1212         dispatchkey[0]    1213 except _Stop as stopinst:    1214     return stopinst.value
>
> KeyError: 91

then I deleted scikit-learn from environment and reinstalled and updated it, but the problem was not resolved and I get the same messages at jupyter notebook.

Comment: The following GitHub Issue might help you: ["fetch_olivetti_faces()" Throws ModuleNotFoundError #19376](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19376)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an effective soloution in these cases, and it is reinstalling. I had to do this with Anacanda.

Answer (score 0):

Reference to the  source code：

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/3f89022fa/sklearn/datasets/_olivetti_faces.py#L37

Download the  fetch_olivetti_faces from

filename="olivettifaces.mat",
url="https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976027",

and load by code:

mfile = loadmat(file_name="olivettifaces.mat")